# Excel VBA find Row With Formula Result #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

How can I get row from result #N/A using vba?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: You can adapt the formula in the next way: `=IFERROR(MATCH(H1;F1:F13,0);"Row "&ROW(H1))`, then filter the range for values beginning with "Row " (Number Filters -> Custom filter... -> Begins with -> Row)...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

example: show the  rows with error in a msgbox

```
Sub GetRow()
Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim colG
Dim errRows As String
Dim shtDebet As Worksheet: Set shtDebet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Debet")

lastRow = shtDebet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
colG = shtDebet.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(colG)
    If IsError(colG(i, 1)) Then
        errRows = errRows & "," & i'append the row with error
    End If
Next i
errRows = Mid(errRows, 2)
MsgBox "These are the rows with errors - " & errRows
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all formulas with errors using `SpecialCells`:

```
Dim errorCells as Range, cell as Range
On Error Resume Next    ' Prevent Runtime error when no errors found
Set errorCells = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
On Error Goto 0
If Not errorCells is Nothing then
    For Each cell in errorCells
        Debug.Print cell.Address, cell.Formula
    Next 
End If
```